# How to post a kafka schema using python

Tags: python, rest, apache-kafka, confluent-schema-registry

I am trying to post a kafka schema using python.

From the CLI I would use a syntax like:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/vnd.schemaregistry.v1+json" --data '{"schema": "{\"type\":\"record\",\"name\":\"VisualDetections\",\"namespace\":\"com.namespace.something\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"vehicle_id\",\"type\":\"int\"},{\"name\":\"source\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"width\",\"type\":\"int\"},{\"name\":\"height\",\"type\":\"int\"},{\"name\":\"annotated_frame\",\"type\":[\"string\",\"null\"]},{\"name\":\"version\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"fps\",\"type\":\"int\"},{\"name\":\"mission_id\",\"type\":\"int\"},{\"name\":\"sequence\",\"type\":{\"type\":\"array\",\"items\":{\"type\":\"record\",\"name\":\"sequence_record\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"frame_id\",\"type\":\"int\"},{\"name\":\"timestamp\",\"type\":\"long\"},{\"name\":\"localization\",\"type\":{\"type\":\"array\",\"items\":{\"type\":\"record\",\"name\":\"localization_record\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"latitude\",\"type\":\"double\"},{\"name\":\"longitude\",\"type\":\"double\"},{\"name\":\"class\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"object_id\",\"type\":\"int\"},{\"name\":\"confidence\",\"type\":\"double\"},{\"name\":\"bbox\",\"type\":{\"type\":\"record\",\"name\":\"bbox\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"x_min\",\"type\":\"int\"},{\"name\":\"y_min\",\"type\":\"int\"},{\"name\":\"x_max\",\"type\":\"int\"},{\"name\":\"y_max\",\"type\":\"int\"}]}}]}}}]}}}]}"}' http://server_ip:8081/subjects/VisualDetections-value/versions/
```

When I tried to tranfer this function to python I tried something like:

```
import requests
import json

topic = 'VisualDetections'
headers = {'Content-Type':  'application/vnd.schemaregistry.v1+json'}
with open(avro_path) as fp:
     data = {'schema': json.load(fp)}
data_json = json.dumps(data)
cmd = 'http://server_ip:8081/subjects/{}-value/versions/'.format(topic)
response = requests.post(cmd, headers=headers, data=data_json)
```

The above returns a code `{"error_code":500,"message":"Internal Server Error"}`. I have tried other options like:

```
with open(avro_path) as fp:
    data = json.load(fp)
```

with error code:

```
"error_code":422,"message":"Unrecognized field: name"
```

In the above the `avro_path` just contains the avro schema in a json file (can be uploaded if useful also).

I am not sure how I could post this data exactly. Also, I did not take into consideration the `-H` argument of post in CLI since I couldn't find a equivalent python argument (not sure it plays any role though). Can anyone provide a solution to this issue.

Comment: `headers=headers` is the same as `-H`... But you might want to look at the server logs, if you can, to see the exact error with the data you're sending for the 500 error

Comment: The `-H` option in `curl` just defines a header, which in this case is ``Content-Type: application/vnd.schemaregistry.v1+json``. You are already doing that with .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the second error, the payload needs to be `{'schema': "schema string"}`

For the first, I think its a matter of the encoding; `json.load` will read the file to a dict rather than just a string.

Notice

```
>>> import json
>>> schema = {"type":"record"}  # example when using json.load() ... other data excluded
>>> json.dumps({'schema': schema})
'{"schema": {"type": "record"}}'  # the schema value is not a string
>>> json.dumps({'schema': json.dumps(schema)})
'{"schema": "{\\"type\\": \\"record\\"}"}'  # here it is
```

Try just reading the file

```
url = 'http://server_ip:8081/subjects/{}-value/versions/'.format(topic)
with open(avro_path) as fp:
     data = {'schema': fp.read().strip()}
     response = requests.post(cmd, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(data))
```

Otherwise, you would `json.load` then use `json.dumps` twice as shown above

You may also try `json=data` rather than `data=json.dumps(data)`